# how to create virtual table on notORM PHP library

Tags: php, sql, notorm

how to create virtual table on notORM PHP library.
Example,I want to make sql like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM `user_share_table` 
      where `user_share_table`.share_valid=1 and
           `user_sharetable`.flag=1
      order by `user_share_table`.share_time desc
     )t JOIN `goods_table` 
          ON `goods_table`.goods_id=`t`.goods_id 
group by `t`.goods_id 
order by `t`.share_time desc 
limit 8
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a view in the database and use it in NotORM.